# How to use Moonlight on Firefox 5?

Tags: firefox, moonlight

After I try install the .xpi file on [the Moonlight homepage](http://go-mono.com/moonlight/), it prompt "Novell Moonlight could not be installed because it is not compatible with Firefox 5.0". It working fine on Chromium, but I want to use it on Firefox, can you help me please.

[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/9Kx0t.png]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try using the [Add-On Compatibility Reporter](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/add-on-compatibility-reporter/) add-on, which disables the version check for add-ons to try out their compatibility with newer versions of Firefox.

The add-on does *not* solve any of the compatibility problems, it just turns the check for Firefox versions off; if the add-on is indeed incompatible with Firefox 5, then allowing the add-on to run may cause unexpected problems.

Answer (score 0):

Which platforms does Moonlight support?

Moonlight should work on any modern 32bit and 64bit Linux distributions under Firefox versions 3.0 through 4.x, as well as Google Chrome, from both stable and dev channels